# MSVC linker seems to link wrong symbol without `__declspec(dllimport)`

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

I have two C++ sources (`a.cc`, `b.cc`), one will be compiled into a shared library (`a.dll`), other will be compiled into an executable (`b.exe`) and link `a.dll`, but MSVC linker doesn't link symbol correctly in `a.dll` without `__declspec(dllimport)`.

---

**a.cc**

```cpp
extern "C" int mysym;
// extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int mysym;

int mysym = 123;
```

```sh
cl -std:c++17 -O2 -fp:fast -EHsc  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um" -DNOMINMAX  -LD .\a.cc -Fe:a.dll  -link -LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64" -LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64" -LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" -EXPORT:mysym
```

**b.cc**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// this is OK
// extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int mysym;

// this is wrong
extern "C" int mysym;

int main() {
    // expect output 123
    std::cerr << mysym << std::endl;
    std::cerr << &mysym << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```sh
cl -std:c++17 -O2 -fp:fast -EHsc .\b.cc a.lib -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um" -DNOMINMAX -Fe:b.exe  -link -LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64" -LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64" -LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64"
```

---

When I execute `b.exe`, the command outputs a random number, not `123`. When I add `__declspec(dllimport)`, the command works as expected.

To figure out why, I dumped the log with `-VERBOSE` in `b`'s build command, and found some clues:

```
// log without __declspec(dllimport)
Searching libraries
    searching a.lib:
      Found mysym
        ref in b.obj
        loaded a.lib(a.dll)

// log with __declspec(dllimport)
Searching libraries
    searching a.lib:
      Found mysym
        ref in a.exp
        loaded a.lib(a.dll)
```

It seems the symbol lookup is wrong, my questions are:

1. If linker didn't found the symbol or symbol lookup is wrong, can it produce a link error, rather than link it to a randomly uninitialized address?
2. Can I tell compiler or linker that `mysym` needs `__declspec(dllimport)` without changing the source code? Because I have a large project, changing the source code is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the function is required, unlike most *nix platforms on Windows symbols are private to modules by default.

You don't have to use declspec(dllexport), there is also the .def file option or even a command line argument (passed to the linker for the DLL project) but either of those are generally much more of a pain than __declspec(dllexport), particularly for C++ symbols because either of those require the decorated symbol name.

It is not possible to get an error when some other symbol is found because the linker has no way of knowing that what was found is not what was desired.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I think it is possible to detect such errors. First dump the link log, then use `dumpbin -SYMBOLS b.obj`, dumpbin will tell me the symbol `mysym` is not exist in `b.obj`. But I think there will be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Extern "C" int mysym（without __declspec(dllimport)） conforms to C++ syntax. So no error will be reported. You can use namespace in DLL to distinguish variables in source code. And it will report an error when link goes wrong.

Use the way below in your DLL can avoid adding __declspec(dllimport) in source code.

```
#ifdef _DLLEXPORT
#define _DLL  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define _DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif 

#define _DLLEXPORT
```